# How to only select one of multiple records in an MS Access report query

Tags: ms-access, duplicates, report

I really hope that someone can help me with this issue.  A co-worker  and I created a database to track the training of over 300 employees.  We created a report, "Progress Report," to show the progress of employees towards a two-year 80 hour requirement for some of the training.  There are certain trainings that have to be taken every year, or two years, but should only be counted once in the progress report.  Here is the sql query:

```
SELECT [Employees Extended].Section, [Employees Extended].[Employee Name], Training.[Training Course], Training.Hours, Training.Category, Training.[Training Start Date], DLookUp("[BeginDate]","[DateIntervals]","Date()>[DateIntervals]![BeginDate]") AS BGN, DLookUp("[EndDate]","[DateIntervals]","Date()<[DateIntervals]![EndDate]") AS [END]
FROM Training INNER JOIN ([Employees Extended] INNER JOIN Employees ON [Employees Extended].[Employee ID] = Employees.[Employee ID]) ON Training.[Employee ID] = Employees.[Employee ID]
WHERE (((Training.Category)="Continuing Education") AND ((Training.[Training Start Date]) Between (DLookUp("[BeginDate]","[DateIntervals]","Date()>[DateIntervals]![BeginDate]")) And (DLookUp("[EndDate]","[DateIntervals]","Date()<[DateIntervals]![EndDate]")))) OR (((Training.[Training Course])="Privacy Training") AND ((Training.[Training Start Date]) Between (DLookUp("[BeginDate]","[DateIntervals]","Date()>[DateIntervals]![BeginDate]")) And (DLookUp("[EndDate]","[DateIntervals]","Date()<[DateIntervals]![EndDate]")))) OR (((Training.[Training Course])="Ethics Training") AND ((Training.[Training Start Date]) Between (DLookUp("[BeginDate]","[DateIntervals]","Date()>[DateIntervals]![BeginDate]")) And (DLookUp("[EndDate]","[DateIntervals]","Date()<[DateIntervals]![EndDate]")))) OR (((Training.[Training Course])="PRA Training") AND ((Training.[Training Start Date]) Between (DLookUp("[BeginDate]","[DateIntervals]","Date()>[DateIntervals]![BeginDate]")) And (DLookUp("[EndDate]","[DateIntervals]","Date()<[DateIntervals]![EndDate]"))));
```

I put this query together from different things that I looked up and was able to get it to work.  However, I'm not sure how, or what, I would need to do get get the results I need.

The Progress Report is mainly for training under the category "Continuing Education".  But there are three mandatory trainings (Privacy Training, Ethics Training, and PRA Training) that also need to be included.  It is these three trainings that will be done every year or two years.

Is there a way to adjust the query that I already have to only pull one of each of these three trainings?

Comment: All good... I was able to work it out.

Comment: Either delete your question then, or answer it yourself. In it's current form, the question is of no use to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

After posting this question I realized that I was making the query more difficult then it needed to be.  I joined three tables to get information I needed when I already had a query that accomplished that.  I then used MAX() to only pull one of the duplicate records and GroupBy to group the results together.  Again, I'm not a pro and I don't know if this was the best way to go about it.

```
SELECT [Training Extended (Test)].Section, [Training Extended (Test)].[Employee Name], [Training Extended (Test)].[Training Course], [Training Extended (Test)].Hours, [Training Extended (Test)].Category, Max([Training Extended (Test)].[Training Start Date]) AS [MaxOfTraining Start Date], DLookUp("[BeginDate]","[DateIntervals]","Date()>[DateIntervals]![BeginDate]") AS BGN, DLookUp("[EndDate]","[DateIntervals]","Date()<[DateIntervals]![EndDate]") AS [END]
FROM [Training Extended (Test)]
GROUP BY [Training Extended (Test)].Section, [Training Extended (Test)].[Employee Name], [Training Extended (Test)].[Training Course], [Training Extended (Test)].Hours, [Training Extended (Test)].Category
HAVING ((([Training Extended (Test)].Category)="Continuing Education") AND ((Max([Training Extended (Test)].[Training Start Date])) Between (DLookUp("[BeginDate]","[DateIntervals]","Date()>[DateIntervals]![BeginDate]")) And (DLookUp("[EndDate]","[DateIntervals]","Date()<[DateIntervals]![EndDate]")))) OR ((([Training Extended (Test)].[Training Course])="Privacy Training") AND ((Max([Training Extended (Test)].[Training Start Date])) Between (DLookUp("[BeginDate]","[DateIntervals]","Date()>[DateIntervals]![BeginDate]")) And (DLookUp("[EndDate]","[DateIntervals]","Date()<[DateIntervals]![EndDate]")))) OR ((([Training Extended (Test)].[Training Course])="Ethics Training") AND ((Max([Training Extended (Test)].[Training Start Date])) Between (DLookUp("[BeginDate]","[DateIntervals]","Date()>[DateIntervals]![BeginDate]")) And (DLookUp("[EndDate]","[DateIntervals]","Date()<[DateIntervals]![EndDate]")))) OR ((([Training Extended (Test)].[Training Course])="PRA Training") AND ((Max([Training Extended (Test)].[Training Start Date])) Between (DLookUp("[BeginDate]","[DateIntervals]","Date()>[DateIntervals]![BeginDate]")) And (DLookUp("[EndDate]","[DateIntervals]","Date()<[DateIntervals]![EndDate]"))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately... after further review of the reports this fix did not work.  The only thing I could think to do was to create a query for each of the types of trainings I was trying to include and then I created a union query.